# Toasts notifications not displaying on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, devise, toastr

Im trying to add toast messages on login/logout, but i get no toast.
Thank u for any advice!

gemfile

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'toastr-rails'
```

app\javascript\packs\application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
toastr = require("toastr")
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/custom.css"
```

app\assets\stylesheets\application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree
 *= require toastr
 *= require_self
```

app\assets\stylesheets\custom.css.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';
@import 'toastr';
```

app\views\shared_message.html.erb

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
<script type="text/javascript">

    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <% type = key.to_s.gsub('alert','error').gsub('notice', 'success') %>
        toastr['<%= type %>'] ('<%= value %>')
        <% end %>
</script>
      <% end %>
```

app\views\layouts\application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/message' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `shared_message.html.erb` you are already substituting alert with error and notice with success. So you're doing this correct. But you should name your file `_message.html.erb` inside the shared folder.

In application.js you should also `//= require toastr` and then, make sure you are in your project folder in terminal and run `bundle install`

Make sure in you gem file to indicate at least 1. Like this

```
gem 'toastr-rails', '~> 1.0'
```

Go to your views in `devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` **and make sure you still have this here**

```
<%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
```

For the error messages above in your views, you will need to add extra work to make it show with toastr.

Go to application.html.erb and ensure you add your partial shared message above the yield, like this:

**and ensure you replace this - Notice how you named the file?**

```
<%= render 'shared/message' %>
<%= yield %>
```

**with this - Notice how you must declare the correct file name?**

```
<%= render 'shared/shared_message' %>
<%= yield %>
```

Above in your question, you named and you created your file in the shared folder as `shared_message.html.erb` which is wrong.

So please better name it `_message.html.erb` it's a partial file, you need to put under score. Also for simplicity just name it `_message.html.erb`